# Linux + manage HTML files under Linux machine

Tags: linux, rhel, html

we have linux server with the following details:

```
LinuxMaster=198.23.47.21
linux redhat 6.5
```

when I browse with this address ( VIA IE )

```
http://LinuxMaster/pageINFO.html
```

I get html screen with details

how to find the **pageINFO.html** in the Linux folders ?

in order to update/edit this html page ?

Comment: did you try `find / -type f -name "pageINFO.html"`  ?

Comment: I prefer not to use the find command because I have partitions with T Byte

Comment: try `locate -b pageINFO.html`

Comment: not have the command locate on my linux machine

Comment: then install the one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are serving it like that, then you are obviously using a web server, like Apache or Nginx.

You can find the default path for

```
apache : /var/www/html/pageInfo.html

nginx : /usr/share/nginx/pageInfo.html
```

If you are using someother webserver, check their documentation for the default paths.
This is assuming, you have not modified the server config files to load files from someother path, if that is the case, I would advise you reach your SysAdmin for more details.